# Система каталогов на javascript (directory tree)?

Tags: javascript

Ищу виртуальную систему каталогов на javascript, максимально простую, компактную и быструю. 
Желательно работающую с node js, либо не привязанную к какой либо БД или серверному языку.

Нужны только функции. Создания, редактирования названия, удаления и перемещения каталогов. 
То есть интерфейс похожий на этот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "редактирование каталогов", не ясно, а в остальном, чем не устраивают стандартные нодовские `fs.mkdir()`, `fs.rmdir()`, `fs.rename()`?

Comment: Мне нужен код отображения на клиенте готовый. Такой же примерно как на скриншоте.

Comment: Вот, в таком виде вопрос стал намного понятнее. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну клиент у вас на картинке и так нарисован (dhtmlx) - не использовал, не знаю.

пользовался jqTree - очень понравился.

серверная сторона - другой компонент. я бы поискал в англоязычном stackoverflow: [ссылка 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511789/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-node-js), [ссылка 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112204/get-all-directories-within-directory-nodejs), [ссылка 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194287/convert-a-directory-structure-in-the-filesystem-to-json-with-node-js)

конечно круто было бы, если было готовое решение в GitHub. Если напишите, киньте ссылку. Будет полезно.

Прошу прощения, сразу не заметил, что задачу у Вас гораздо сложнее: вы хотите виртуальную файловую систему. Но в первом приближении можно сделать, чтобы она 1-в-1 отображалась в реальную файловую систему на сервере.

Comment: Использую jqTree, как раз подходит